# Understanding crystal resonator symbols - which one is 24Mhz?

Tags: frequency, oscillator, measurement, crystal, frequency-measurement

So, I'm in need of a 24MHz crystal to drive an AVR microcontroller. I've got some crystals that I've desoldered off some old, useless equipment. I've found three crystals that have '24' on their packaging:
HC 24.00
TXC 24.0NQ4L
24.00R4L

Google search turned out nothing, so I don't know whether any of these is 24MHz, or 2.4MHz, or some other values. From what I've managed to find, 24MHz have three 0's after the dot, but I couldn't find if 2.4MHz quartz ones have only two 0's or not.

I don't have a counter to measure how many ticks these can generate (too expensive :/ )

So, to expand the question a little bit, as I have more crystals in my collection: How to find out, without googling, looking only on the number on the package, how many Hz's are there?

Comment: Unless you are using an XMega the maximum clock frequency is 20 MHz. It may work at 24, it may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal point on crystal oscillators or crystal resonators is typically at the **millions** place or less often the **thousands** place, in hertz. The number of digits after the decimal point does not affect the frequency.

Thus, a 24 MHz part would be labeled `24.00` or `24.000`, a 2.4 MHz part would be labeled `2.400` or (not seen this yet, but it is possible) `2.40`.

A 32768 Hz crystal would be labeled `32.768` - those are common for RTC applications.

Other than 32.768 and a few other low frequency crystals used for very specific purposes, it is almost always a megahertz number marked on the part.

Comment: The number of trailing zeroes (or any other number) is an indication of the accuracy of the crystal.